# Using C# or jQuery to cause Outlook window to open with a templated body...

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, email, templates

Is it possible, and if so how, to use C# or jQuery in an MVC web application to have a button or a link on a page cause Outlook to open up with a set body and subject?

Basically, I want the user to be able to choose a template from a dropdownlist and then click a button or link saying 'Send Templated Email' and have the button/link open up the client's Outlook or default email application with the subject and body populated by the template that they chose.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<a href="mailto:email@emu.edu?subject=Subject&body=Body Text">

...

// something like this
$('#btn').click(function () {
    $('#link').attr('href', 'mailto:' + $('#email').text() + '?body=' + template[idx].body + '&subject=' + template[idx].subject); 
})
```

Comment: +1 That's correct to shell an email, but it will open up the *default* mail client -- not specifically outlook.

Comment: From OP: "have the button/link open up the client's Outlook or default email application"

Comment: @joeTuskan : is this possible with an attachemnt? I need to open default client with pdf statement attached to it from c# web application

Comment: @Mini, nope. But C# has the ability to with MailMessage class

Comment: @JoeTuskan : what i need to do is open outlook compose window on client machine with an attachment from a web application... ??